# Getting names of inherited classes in JavaParser

Tags: java, javaparser

In my example I have something like this:

```
public class Example extends Random, Math {...}
```

Using JavaParser I want to get the names of classes that are after 'extends' keyword.

How can I do it?

On the site of JavaParser I have found something like this:

```
compilationUnit.getNodesByType(FieldDeclaration.class).stream().
    filter(f -> f.getModifiers().contains(PUBLIC) && 
            !f.getModifiers().contains(STATIC)).
    forEach(f -> System.out.println("Check field at line " + f.getBegin().get().line));
```

Or maybe it should be done in visit() method?

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to look for the [getExtends](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.2.3/com/github/javaparser/ast/body/ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.html#getExtendedTypes--) method

Source: I am a JavaParser committer

Comment: Thanks! It helped me pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code is very useful :

```
public class inheritedClasses extends VoidVisitorAdapter<Void> {

//If you use a file which contained java code source
 private static final String FILE_PATH ="//put the path of your file here;if your file is in the same package use just src/main.... but if it is in another package use the whole path "; 

   public void visit(ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration cid , Void arg){
        super.visit(cid,arg);
       //I guess you just want to print the inherited class's name at the console
          System.out.println(""+cid.getExtendedTypes());
  }

public static void main(String[] args){

  CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser(new File(FILE_PATH));

    VoidVisitor<Void> methodinherts = new inheritedClasses();
        methodinherts.visit(cu,null);  




}



}
```